# Tuning a stable baselines agent for a custom env

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I made a game and I am trying to make it work with stable baselines. I've tried different algorithms
I've tried reading stable baselines documentation, but i can't figure out where to start tuning.
My game is here: https://github.com/AbdullahGheith/BlockPuzzleGym

And this is the code i ran to train it:

```
import gym
import blockpuzzlegym
from stable_baselines import PPO2

env = gym.make("BlockPuzzleGym-v0")
model = PPO2('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1)
model.learn(250000)

for _ in range(10000):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
```

I tried 25000000 timesteps, but it still wouldn't work.
As you might tell, i am new to ML, and this is my first project. Any indications are welcome.

I tried using the parameters the MiniGrid parameters from [stable baselines zoo](https://github.com/araffin/rl-baselines-zoo/blob/master/hyperparams/ppo2.yml) (without the env wrapper)

Comment: What do you mean "where to start tuning?" Do you mean from which time step? Also, what do you mean when you say "it still wouldn't work?" Do you mean that the model's not converging?

Comment: I guess that i have to tune some of the algorithm parameters in order for it to work. What i mean by "it wont work" is that the agent is not really "getting the game". It's barely getting more reward than ~100, while i can easily get 1000 myself by playing.
Timesteps should not be my issue, i've tried letting it run on 26 processes for the whole night, but the agent isnt improving.
If i had to guess, it would be my observation space that it doesn't understand. Check my github, i wrote a little about that. Maybe thats not "out of the box" material and thats why my learning code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can see that you used simple default MlpPolicy that includes two fully connected layers with size 64. How to implement your own network?
Here is a docs how to implement your own network. https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html

You should understand that any model in stable-baselines corresponds to following structure:
feature_extractor -> mlp_extractor -> policy\value networks.

So, you could add `policy_kwargs` to the model, where `policy_kwargs` is a `dict` with:

```
policy_kwargs = dict(
        feature extractor=custom_extractor,
        net_arch=[64, dict(vf=[16], pi=[16])]
    )
```

Here you can see `net_arch` corresponds to structure of mlp_extractor and for policy\value nets. `custom_extractor` is a funciton that you can implement that would process your input data to fully connected layer at the end. You can implement here any structure of a model that you want. For example, there is a default cnn_extractor from library:

```
def nature_cnn(scaled_images, **kwargs):    
    activ = tf.nn.relu
    layer_1 = activ(conv(scaled_images, 'c1', n_filters=32, filter_size=8, stride=4, init_scale=np.sqrt(2), **kwargs))
    layer_2 = activ(conv(layer_1, 'c2', n_filters=64, filter_size=4, stride=2, init_scale=np.sqrt(2), **kwargs))
    layer_3 = activ(conv(layer_2, 'c3', n_filters=64, filter_size=3, stride=1, init_scale=np.sqrt(2), **kwargs))
    layer_3 = conv_to_fc(layer_3)
    return activ(linear(layer_3, 'fc1', n_hidden=512, init_scale=np.sqrt(2)))
```